# python html webscraping from a table with td type

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to the webscrape the Price of the Phuthuma Nathi share from the https://www.eese.co.za/ website. When I use inspect element I see the price is in a td style line. I've tried a few ways to access this line but in all the following methods I can't see the current price anywhere in the output

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client

# URl to web scrape from
page_url = "https://www.eese.co.za/"

# opens the connection and downloads html page from url
uClient = uReq(page_url)

# parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
# as if it were a json data type.
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

print("attempt 1")
containers = page_soup.findAll('td',{'style':'text-align: right;'})
print (containers)

print("\nattempt 2")
containers2 = page_soup.findAll('td')
print (containers2)

print("\nattempt 3")
containers3 = page_soup.findAll('tr')
print (containers3)

print("\nattempt 4")
containers4 = page_soup.findAll('div',{'data-asynccontent':'B3F9538F9B4C0DF4780EAE6ABF09A6F6'})
print (containers4)
```

Comment: It looks like the content you are after is being fetched in XHR after the page loads, maybe a headless browser in selenium would make it easier to find

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used selenium before but I'll check it out